# python--can we find the directory of running processes using psutil?

Tags: python

I just want to kill all running "python" processes which are running from particular directory.. Means the files(sample.py) resides in specific folder.

```
For ex: C:\myFolder\*
```

Using psutil can we find the path of the processes or kill all the process which are from **C:\myFolder\*** except some processess?

```
 import psutil
 for process in psutil.process_iter():
    print process.cmdline:
```

Comment: Location of the Python file? Or the working directory?

Comment: Ya location of the python files

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment, if you want to find file location for the running python scripts - use `psutil.Process.name() == 'python'` to filter the python processes. Then use `os.path.abspath()` to get the full path.

The following code example might work:

```
import psutil
import os

"""
Python script path using psutil
"""

processes = filter(lambda p: psutil.Process(p).name() == "python", psutil.pids())

scripts = []
paths = []
for pid in processes:
    try:
        scripts.append(psutil.Process(pid).cmdline()[1])
    except IndexError:
    pass

for script in scripts:
    paths.append(os.path.abspath(script))

print paths
```

Comment: It is giving the current work directory of the above file not the directory of the script we are passing to abspath.  I have copied and run above code in c:\sample\path.py and the processes scripts are c:\Myfolder\test.py and c:\Myfolder\result.py....When I run path.py i am getting the output like c:\sample\result.py and c:\sample\test.py

Answer (score 1):

If the scripts path in `cmdline[1]` is not an absolute path, you can use `cwd()` from `psutil` to get the working dir, after that, join the dir string with the script path string, and then you can get the location of the python scripts.